# Let $G$ be a group. Let $G/K$ be an abelian group. Prove that $C=\{e\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm stuck at this exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group, with $|G|=pqr$, $p,q,r$ different primes, $q<r$, $r \not\equiv 1$ (mod $q$), $qr<p$. Also suppose that $p \not\equiv 1$ (mod $r$), $p \not\equiv 1$ (mod $q$). Let $C$ (the commutator of $G$) and $K$ be subgroups of $G$, with $C \leq K$, $K \trianglelefteq G$ and $|K|=q$. $K$ is the unique Sylow $q$-subgroup on $G$ (so $K \trianglelefteq G$). Let $G/K$ be an abelian group. Prove that $C=\{e\}$.

I tried using Lagrange theorem, knowing that $C\leq K$, and then $|C|=\{1\ or\ q\}$. But I don't know how to eliminate the option $|C|=q$.

This is a little part from a longer exercise. The definition of $C$ is $C=\langle[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1} \mid a,b\in G \rangle$, $G/C$ is abelian too.

Thank you.

Comment: You must be missing something, since $K = C$ satisfies your problem statement.

Comment: Yes, that's what I came up with too. I'll complete the question with some more information. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidWheeler It changes something if $K$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$?

Comment: $G= D_6 \times C_5$, $p,q,r=3,2,5$ gives $C=K$. Also how is $H$ involved?

Comment: @DerekHolt There're more restrictions. I'm going to edit it and put the whole exercise because it's leading to confusions.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}$$G/K$ is abelian of order $p r$, thus cyclic. If you can prove that $K \le Z(G)$, then it follows that $G$ is abelian.

To prove this, let $K = \Span{z}$. We have that $G/C_{G}(K)$ has order dividing $q-1$.

Let $a$ be an element of order $p$, and $b$ an element of order $r$. Since $p > q r > q$, we have that $a$ centralizes $z$. Since $r > q$, we have that $b$ centralizes $z$. Hence $z$ is central, as required.

---

Lemma. Let $G$ be a group. Suppose $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic. Then $G$ is abelian.

Proof. Suppose $G = \langle a, Z(G) \rangle$. Then two arbitrary elements of $G$ can be written as $a^{i} z, a^{j} w$, with $i, j$ integers, and $z, w \in Z(G)$. Thus
$$
(a^{i} z) (a^{j} w) = a^{i} a^{j} z w = a^{j} a^{i} w z = (a^{j} w) (a^{i} z).
$$

Comment: Hi @Andreas . There's a way to prove it without using the centralizer? I think that they want us to deduce it, like if it was easier than this.

Comment: @Abrahamlure, perhaps you have further information about $H$, which at the moment, as noted by Derek Holt, plays no role?

Comment: ... I'm so sorry. I use to name $H$ to a subgroup of $G$. Every $H$ is a $K$. It's edited now.

Comment: I think that the important thing here is that $K$ is the unique Sylow $q$-subgroup. There's some way to say that $C\neq K$ because $K$ is the unique Sylow $q$-subgroup?

Comment: @Abrahamlure, no way that way.

Comment: why showing that $K \leq Z(G)$ implies $G$ is abelian? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @Abrahamlure, I have just added the relevant Lemma.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't found any easier way to do my exercise, so I'm going to try to understand your resolution.

Comment: @Abrahamlure, please feel free to ask any further questions.